# Power Shell script does not return result of Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, splistitem, library

I have written a below PowerShell script to get items of a library for SharePoint 2013

```
$spData = $web.Lists["EmployeeDocument"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]
$fieldsItems = $spData.Items

$result = $fieldsItems | select Title,FolderCategory

$filterItem =  $fieldsItems | ? {$_.FolderCategory -eq "Help"}
```

This script does not return the result and filter of the Library.

Where as, below script return 3 items count:

```
$spData.Items.Count
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need Item count library?

Comment: @Mikhail: I have a mentioned $spData.Items.Count to specify that library "EmployeeDocument" consist of three items...

Comment: First try to don't cast as libary, try to jandle it like a normal list. I had aame sideeffects with this too two weeks ago. Only the plain list gave me the items back.

Comment: Sorry, its don't work even after using the normal list.

Comment: I suggest you print the results before assigning, so you can see what you are doing wrong. e.g. $fieldsItems | select Title, FolderCategory. Odds are your FolderCategory property is empty

Answer (score 0):

try to fetch the list as below:

```
web.lists.GetByTitle("TestList")
```